# CountingSort warning

Tags: c

I write a counting sort algorithm, but when declare a Count array, i have a warning(variable length array used), and it's not gonna work.

```
void CountingSort(int A[]) {
    int B[N+1];

    int max = A[0];
    for(int i = 1; i<=N; i++) {
       if(A[i] > max)
          max = A[i];
    }
    int C[max];

    for(int i=0; i<=max;i++){
        C[i]=0;
    }
    for(int j = 1; j<=N; j++){
      C[A[j]]++;
    }
    for(int i=1; i<=max; i++){
       C[i] += C[i-1];
    }
    for(int j=N; j>0; j--){
      B[C[A[j]]] = A[j];
      C[A[j]] -= 1;
    }

    for (int i = 1; i <= N; i++){
      A[i]=B[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean it *doesn't* work?  Because I would normally expect a compiler that doesn't support VLAs at all to reject your code altogether instead of emitting a warning.  It is reasonably likely that your code will work fine for inputs whose size and range is not too large.  Or, at least, not to break on such inputs on account of VLA use.

Comment: In any case, the most flexible alternative to VLAs is dynamically-allocated storage.  Dynamically allocating your `C` and maybe `B` arrays should get rid of the warnings, at least with respect to the function presented.

Comment: Perhaps you are declaring a variable array length? In ANSI C, you're not allowed to write something like this: int n = 5; int array[n];

Comment: So it's wrong ? : int C[max];      How to create C array with max length ?

Comment: @TamásSzabó use dynamic memory allocation

Answer (score 0):

Static field memory is not enough for creating int field ranging from 0 to INT_MAX (2^64 or 2^32 - depends on OS)

For example:
If max = 10^12, then "int C[max]" line will look for 8000 GB on stack where limit is aprox. 10 MB (depends on OS settings)

In your code you are using static field. Static field i using function stack memory. Limit for function stack memory is usually somewhere around 10 MB. That mean your limit is aprox. 1 000 000. BUT!

You can use dynamic field, which is using heap instead of stack. That mean you can use all your RAM. But you have to allocate space for it and free it at the end of your program.

```
int *C = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*max)); // get some space on heep
... // (Code where you are using C[index])
free(C); // when you no longer need C pointer space on heap.
```

more info about dynamic allocating [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dynamic-memory-allocation-in-c-using-malloc-calloc-free-and-realloc/).

Also, you should use counting sort on data from specific known range like from 0 to 10^8 (10^8 should use 800 MB or 400 MB of RAM - depends on OS). Bigger numbers are going to use gigabytes of RAM and your RAM can over flow.